# What is the meaning of ":" in the following program....Charminar:...?

Tags: dev-c++

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{       
    int i=1;
    **Charminar:**

    printf("%d",i+1);
    if(i==3) break;
    if(i<=5) goto Charminar;

    return 0;
}
```

The word `Charminar` is not giving any error but I just want to know the meaning of it.

Comment: I mean we haven't initialize still it is not giving any error..

Comment: Notice that Dev-C++ is *not* a compiler (but some IDE). So compile your program on the command line like (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -o yourbinary` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Comment: And `Charminar:` is a **label** (target of a `goto`)

Comment: Did you add the pairs of asterisks to highlight the syntax?